# QGIS distance matrix: wrong metric distance

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I used the lineair distance matrix tool in QGIS 2.6 My coordination system is metric (national Dutch RD new) The results have the wrong decimals, as shown below. How can I fix this? (showing unique distances only)

```
InputID TargetID    Distance by matrix  real distance   
3   2   914.753.872.032 914     meter
3   1   119.476.303.875 1,19    km
4   1   156.770.528.678 1,56    km
4   3   162.709.997.483 1,62    km
4   2   226.796.645.372 2,26    km
6   5   241.698.218.226 2,41    km
6   3   614.677.367.185 6,14    km
6   4   631.106.480.203 6,31    km
6   2   693.828.353.563 6,93    km
6   1   723.724.716.201 7,23    km
2   1   105.868.974.731 1,05    km
5   3   38.004.119.442  3,8     km
5   4   390.398.472.686 3,9     km
5   2   46.440.219.167  4,64    km
5   1   484.470.336.769 484     meter
```

Comment: What is the language of your system locale (Settings->Options->Locale)? What is the detected active locale on your system?

Comment: I've just checked, that's both Dutch. Seems fine, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know that the Netherlands is one of the countries that also uses arabic numerals with decimal comma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark). For this reason, it looks like as a locale problem. In Spain (which also uses decimal comma), to avoid locale problems, I use my QGIS with U.S.English language and "Override system locale" (Settings->Options->Locale).

To test correct operation of "distance matrix tool" in my system, I loaded a point vector layer in QGIS and ran the tool.

[image]

I printed my distance matrix as csv file where I selected the first record for verification purpose (in red):

[image]

In the next image I selected the points with id 0-4 and measured its distance with "Measure Line Tool". The result was comparable to the one in csv file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works I guess. What I did was the other way around: in my computer settings: START, COMPUTER, CONTROL PANEL, DATE TIME LANGUAGE AND REGIONAL OPTIONS, CHANGE THE FORMAT OF NUMBERS DATES AND TIMES, REGIONAL OPTIONS, CUSTOMIZE, NUMBERS: DECIMAL SYMBOL = point & DIGIT GROUPING SYMBOL= comma. Perfect .csv output tables!

Answer (score 1):

Did you open the csv with a text editor or with Excel? Excel gets confused with delimter commas, thousand points and decimal commas; depending on your computers locale.

If you replace the delimiter comma by semicolons, it should work. A good text editor like notepad++ for Windows can do this easily.